# Getting error: 'NU3008: The package integrity check failed' when trying to restore nuget packages during my TeamCity build

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-server

I have TeamCity building a project pulled down from SVN on a build machine under the LOCALUSER account.

The first step it takes is to restore nuget packages using the nuget installer from the .csproj file. The files all seem to be pulled down successfully, however, during installation of the packages I get the error:

```
NU3008: The package integrity check failed.
```

This is strange, as I am able to restore the packages into my user directory through visual studio if I open up the project that TeamCity has pulled down, without any issues.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: By any chance, is your CI running on Linux or Mac, or are you running nuget.exe through Mono?

Answer (score 0):

[As the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3008)

> Please ensure that the package has not been tampered with since signing. If this was a temporary problem, then you can fix this by clearing your local cache(s) by running nuget locals -Clear all command. However, if the problem persists then please inform the package source and the package author.

Note you'll need to do this on the user and account with the problem, in other words the build agent account on the Team City agent machine. When you restored the project on your machine on your account, it might have downloaded from a different NuGet feed, assuming the package is available from multiple feeds. If the problem was transient, then it's unlikely to happen to you on a different machine at a different time. If the bad package is in the team city agent's global packages folder, then it needs to be deleted, again as it's local to that machine & account.

Comment: I have the Disable looking up packages from local machine cache option enabled in my NuGet Installer options in the build step, so I assume this isn't a problem stemming from a cached version. I've successfully pulled down the references through visual studio on multiple machines now, it seems only TeamCity has a problem with getting them.

Comment: I don't know what the "Disable looking up packages from local machine cache" option is, or how it works, but it's better to verify rather than assume, when you're experiencing problems. Maybe it works differently to how you expect, or maybe it's buggy and doesn't work at all. The NuGet docs say that the files should be deleted, so that's my suggestion.

Comment: Also, if you haven't tried already, i suggest trying the latest nuget.exe, as it has the most bug fixes. Currently it's 5.1.0. You didn't say if you restored using the dotnet cli or nuget.exe, or what version you used.

Comment: I've changed my approach to building, where before I was using the built in NuGet installer from TeamCity, I'm now using the NuGet.exe CLI, version 5.1.0, running under the SYSTEM account. I run the clear locals command, set my sources and then run a nuget restore. The build is now failing to due to an incorrect version from one of my sources. I can run the exact same process under my user account on the same machine with no issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the build agent is only trying to pull from     https://api.nuget.org/

Comment: make sure there's a nuget.config checked into your repo and it contains all your package sources. The VS UI to edit package sources can only edit your user profile nuget.config, so you must edit the solution nuget.config manually.